# SyncLock for AsyncOperation

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, synclock

I have a method Update() that's called by a AsyncOperation through .Post(). When I place a MessageBox in that function, I get multiple messageboxes, and I'm trying to understand why that happens.

The Messagebox should halt execution of Update() untill 'OK' is clicked, but because of .Post() I get re-entrance in Update(), causing the next messagebox to appear before the previous one is closed.

My first thought was to place SyncLock in Update(), so that it never can run simultanously, but it had no effect. When I output the .ManagedThreadID in the MessageBox, all calls have the same thread ID, so it seems logical that SyncLock has no effect, because it only blocks different threads.

So can someone explain what's going on here? How can a single thread execute the same function simultanously?

Comment: Post example test-case/code. I suspect that *different* objects are being synchronized upon or the lock is otherwise ... funny.

Comment: I'm using this code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hk12d4y(v=vs.80).aspx The MessageBox is in the event handler for ProgressChanged.

Comment: @Joshua, a *simple* code block will help a lot. All async operations get executed in a thread pool and every time `Update` is called there might be different thread to process it. It is also not really clear to me what `SyncLock` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A message box is only modal on the thread it is displayed on.  The UI thread in your case, as it should.  It cannot prevent the worker threads from calling Post(), you'll thus continue to get more message boxes.  SyncLock cannot work either, it is re-entrant on the same thread.  A simple boolean flag that you set to true before the MessageBox.Show() call and to false after will do the job, don't call Show again if it is set to true.

Or just not using MessageBox, Debug.Print() is a good way to trace.  Text goes to the Output window by default.  A debugger breakpoint can do wonders too.

Comment: I am not using MessageBoxes in real-life, it is just a simulation for when the calculations in that function take more time to complete than it takes for the worker to fire the next event. I always want the previous calculation to finish, before it's called again. So I cannot use the boolean flag, because it will make the calculation get skipped, instead of queued. I can write my own queing mechanism, but I hoped there was some build-in function queing like SyncLock does.

Comment: You don't need a queuing mechanism, code that runs on the UI thread is automatically serialized.  It can do only one thing at a time.  Mentioning message box when you don't actually use it was unwise.  If there's anything else in this code that can cause re-entrancy, like DoEvents(), then you'll have to remove it.  Look at the call stack to have an idea what that might be.

Comment: The MessageBox was only to illustrate the problem easier, I have nothing else that can cause re-entrance, so I should be fine. Does the MessageBox call DoEvents() behind the scenes, or why is there a difference between a messagebox vs a long calculation?

Comment: MessageBox pumps a message loop, similar to DoEvents.  So, what is the real problem here or did you not actually use SyncLock either?

Comment: I was afraid for function re-entrance, I expected the Messagebox to behave similar to Sleep(), now I know it's not. Thanks!